# Angular JS ng-repeat and the 'this'

Tags: angularjs, this, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm new in AngularJS, but did some jQuery before. i've got a problem to understand how to get the clicked element / it's parent to make some changes like change the text, an icon or a class in the item where i made the click.

the simple HTML:

```
<ul ng-controller="basketCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in item">
        <button ng-click="addToBasket(Itemid,this,whatever)">
             <i class="myBasketicon">
             <span>Buy now</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

what i want to do:

```
$scope.addTobasket = function (id, elem, whatever){
   // to some JSON-Server-stuff - that works perfect

   // now my problems, : 

   //change this -> myBasketIcon -> myOKicon
   //change this -> span text  Buy now-> Thanks for buying
   // give the this -> li an class => 'changed'

}
```

I really tried a lot, f.e with ng-model in the tags, arrays... search the web half the day... but didn't find anything that matches my problem.
Maybe it's just the way of thinking not the angular way... so please help :O)

Kind regard from Hamburg, Germany

Timo

Comment: Instead of "this", use $event. It should be similar to your jQuery days from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add methods for the icon class and text that change their results based on the state of the object, or use custom a custom directive. You definitely don't want to be doing any DOM manipulation (changing text/classes etc) the way you would have done with jQuery.

For the method-based approach, something like this for your markup:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in item">
    <button ng-click="addToBasket(item)">
         <i ng-class="getClass(item)">
         <span>{{getMessage(item)}}</span>
    </button>
</li>
```

and on your controller:

```
.controller('ShoppingListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.getClass = function(item) {
        return item.inBasket ? 'myOkIcon' : 'myBasketIcon';
    };

    $scope.getMessage = function(item) {
        return item.inBasket ? 'Thanks for buying' : 'Buy now';
    };
})
```

This could also be done with a custom directive which is a super powerful way to do things (and definitely worth figuring out) but may be overkill for just starting out. If you find you are adding a lot if methods for doing these sorts of things go with directives.

Comment: like the first answer: that's what i was looking for! to add item.inBasket and so on to the model is the missing link ;O)

Comment: okay... one last thing: i wrote that i make some JSON-Server-stuff to show the total-basket-price, amount, etc... and also changes of in the item itself. this is made with $scope.BasketModel = returnData ; returndata comes from the http-request, as you can imagine. so the question: How do i map the 'old item' to the 'new item'?

Comment: Just assign the new data to the same attribute on the scope and Angular will pick up on the changes.

Comment: Hi, that's what i already did, but it doesn't work. i've got a init-load-function with the same $scope.BasketModel = returnData . but when i run $scope.getClass, etc AFTER i loaded the new data into  $scope.BasketModel nothing happens. i tested it with a time-out: first item.inBasket = true, then time-out with 2sec and then $scope.BasketModel = returnData.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this by changing a property (angular way), no need to access the element in the ng-click handler,and using ng-class and angular binding on that property.

```
<ul ng-controller="basketCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'changed': item.added}">
        <button ng-click="addToBasket(item)">
             <i ng-class="{'myBasketicon':!item.added,'myOKicon':item.added }">
             <span>{{item.added ? "Thanks for buying" : "Buy now"}}</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and in your handler just do:

```
$scope.addTobasket = function (item){
   item.added = true;
}
```

Most cases, whole purpose of using angular is to avoid DOM manipulation and let angular manage it, you just deal with the models/viewmodels and bindings.